# Someone has put phishing files on my server

Tags: php, lamp, phishing

Recently i found some phishing files (PHP/HTML) on my server which were previously not present. I deleted them but later another set of files reappeared.

This is happening for all the sites hosted on my server even after changing the admin panel and FTP credentials .

**My Question:**

Is it possible for someone using some nulled software to get my server ftp credentials and put those files in the server?

Comment: I assume this server has outward-facing WWW sites run via PHP code, and isn't just an FTP server?

If so, have you examined server access logs to see if any unusual activity can be detected?

Comment: I had answered this quite some time ago for another person but can't find it.  In short, if it's a shared hosting provider like GoDaddy it may not be your account that is compromised.  It could be someone else.  I would report it to your hosting provider and inform them of the PHP injection.